# Cell automat in Java

Tags: java, arrays, cell, automata

I am trying to create a similar model of Conway's game of life in Java, but adapted to some specific conditions and behavoiur of cells. I do not have enough experience in programming so, I will be greateful if you can give me some answers.

I have this code so far:

```
package project_cells;

import java.util.Random;

public class Field {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int size = 4;
        char[][] field = new char[size][size];          // field 
        char[] cell_type = {'A','B','a','b'};          // fill out vector with cell type

        for(int i = 0; i <size; i++ ) {                 // checking the matrix positions
            for (int j = 0; j <size; j++) {
                Random rand = new Random();  
                int celltype_option = rand.nextInt((3-0)+1)+0;       // creating a random number from 0 to 3 
                field[i][j]=cell_type[celltype_option];             // Filling the field with cell types
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Клетки первого поколения");                     // checking the first generation of cells
        for (int x=0; x < field.length; x++) {
            System.out.print("|");
            for (int y=0; y < field[x].length; y++) {
                System.out.print (field[x][y]);
                if (y!=field[x].length-1) System.out.print("\t");

            }
            System.out.println("|");
        }
    }
}
```

With this code I get only the array with the 4 type of cells (A,B,a,b) A and B change its behaviour, a and b don't change.

The issue is that I need to create 3 ways to verify the neighbors: 1. When cell verifies only 4 neighbors (up, right, left, down). 2. When cell verifies 8 surrounding neighbors and 3. When cell verifies any random neighbor.

How can I get such verifications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The left and right neighbors of `x` are `x-1` and `x+1`. They only exist if they are `>= 0` and `<= size - 1`:

```
for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i+= 2) { // i = -1, +1
    final int neighborIndex = x + i; 
    if (neighborIndex >= 0 && neighborIndex < size) {
        // ...   
    }
}
```

The up/down case can be handled analogously.

To get all eight neighbors, iterate from `x-1` to `x+1` and the inside it from `y-1` to `y+1` (again, only if `>=0` and `< size`) and filter out the center `(x, y)`:

```
for (int xNeighbor = Math.max(0, x - 1); xNeighbor <= Math.min(size - 1, x + 1); xNeighbor += 1) {
    for (int yNeighbor = Math.max(0, y - 1); yNeighbor <= Math.min(size - 1, y + 1); yNeighbor += 1) {
        if (!(xNeighbor == x && yNeighbor == y)) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

To get a random neighbor, first count the number of neighbors and then use `rand.nextInt(numNeighbors)` to select one.